# Updating ParseUI and Facebook SDK by cocoapods

Tags: facebook, parse-platform, cocoapods, parseui

I am trying to install ParseUI, Facebook SDK by cocoapods. Here is my pod file:

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
pod 'ParseUI', '~> 1.1.3'
pod 'Parse', '~> 1.7.2'
pod 'Facebook-iOS-SDK', '~> 4.1.0'
pod 'ParseFacebookUtilsV4', '~>1.7.2'
pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.5.3'
```

After pod install, I got a warning

> "Facebook-iOS-SDK has been deprecated in favor of FBSDKCoreKit".

1. Does this mean I should uninstall "Facebook-iOS-SDK" by removing the line

   ```
   pod 'Facebook-iOS-SDK', '~> 4.1.0'
   ```

   and pod install again?
2. Does ParseUI work with pod 'Facebook-iOS-SDK', '~> 4.1.0'?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

1) The reason you're seeing this warning is because Facebook iOS SDK deprecated the old `pod 'Facebook-iOS-SDK', '4.1.0'` decleration, as noted in their [API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started#sdk):

> You can also include the SDK via CocoaPods by adding pod
>   "FBSDKCoreKit" to your Podfile (and repeat for FBSDKLoginKit,
>   FBSDKShareKit as appropriate).

So instead, write the following in your `Podfile`:

```
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit',  '4.1.0'
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit', '4.1.0'
pod 'FBSDKShareKit', '4.1.0'
```

2) ParseUI works with the new Facebook iOS SDK (4.x) from version 1.1.2.